# Cellular prism operator

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, classifying-spaces

I have a question.

Given a nulhomotopic map $f : X \rightarrow Y$, we can define a prism operator
$P : C_n(X) \rightarrow C_{n+1}(Y)$ between singular chains.

Then do we have a cellular prism operator $Q : C_n^{CW}(X) \rightarrow C_{n+1}^{CW}(Y)$, where $C_{*}^{CW}$ denotes cellular chains?

If not, is there some kind of condition where we can get such $Q$?
I think we can kind of extend the prism operator $P$ using acyclic models, but I do not see how (or maybe there's another way of doing it?).

PS) Edited to one question only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $h\colon X\times I\to Y$ be a cellular homotopy between cellular maps $f$ and $g$. There is a canonical isomorphism
$$C^\mathrm{CW}_\ast(X\times I)\cong C^\mathrm{CW}_\ast(X)\otimes C^\mathrm{CW}_\ast(I)$$
coming from the product CW-structure on $X\times I$.
Now $C_\ast^\mathrm{CW}(I)$ has $[0]$ and $[1]$ as basis elements in degree $0$ and $[I]$ in degree $1$. Furthermore, $d([I]) = [0]-[1]$. If we put $s(x) = (-1)^iC_\ast^\mathrm{CW}(h)(x\otimes [I])$ for $x\in C_i^\mathrm{CW}(X)$, then
\begin{align}d_Y(s(x)) &= (-1)^id_Y(h_\ast(x\otimes [I]) )\\
&=(-1)^ih_\ast d_{X\times I}(x\otimes [I]) \\
&= (-1)^i h_\ast(d_Xx\otimes [I]+(-1)^ix\otimes d[I]) \\
&= h_\ast(x\otimes d[I])-(-1)^{i-1}h_\ast(d_Xx\otimes [I]) \\
&= h_\ast (x\otimes [0])-h_\ast(x\otimes [1])-s(d_Xx)\\
&=f_\ast(x)-g_\ast(x)-s(d_Xx),\end{align}
so this yields a chain homotopy from $C_\ast^\mathrm{CW}(f)$ to $C_\ast^\mathrm{CW}(g)$.

Comment: Thank you! Could you please explain why "s" is the chain homotopy? Also I'm not able to see the canonical isomorphism there...

Comment: @wanderer Do you know how to put a CW-structure on the product of CW-complexes?

Comment: Ah! I get the canonical isomorphism now :) How about the chain homotopy?

Comment: I thought you would comment on it, but seems like you've edited the answer, so I saw it recently :) Thanks! One last question, shouldn't it be $(-1)^{i}$ instead of $(-1)^{i-1}$ there? (The fourth equality there - $h_{*}$ is linear, so I get that it would split linearly, but...) Sorry for the stupid questions :).

Comment: Ah oops, I missed the minus sign there! Thanks a bunch :)